# Python: How to do the conditional removal of letters from the column in dataframe in python?

Tags: python, pandas

```
data = {'period':['chy1md','chy2md','chy6md',chy6L6L1y,'chy6L6L5y','chy6L6L10y']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Expected output:

```
new_df = {'period':['1md','2md','6md',1y,'5y','10y']}
```

May I get help to get the above expected output. I want conditional strip from the column based on length of the column values. I dont want to hard code the letters to be removed. It is so because I have many files and there are different names in the columns. Conditional stripping help me to format other files.

Comment: You have to explain the rule you want to base your strip, it is impossible to guess it

Comment: `df['period'] = df['period'].str[-3:]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, this woudl do:

```
df.period.str.extract('(\d+\D+)$')
```

Output:

```
     0
0  1md
1  2md
2  6md
3   1y
4   5y
5  10y
```

Comment: Great. This is working.I wonder if you can share some stuff related to it.

Comment: @mathew `.str.extract` accepts a regex pattern. You can read about regex from just about anywhere :-).

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
result = df['period'].str.replace('(chy|6L6L)', '')
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
0    1md
1    2md
2    6md
3     1y
4     5y
5    10y
Name: period, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. But i dont want to hard code 'chy/6L6L because i have multiple files to get strip. Dont we have any method to do stripping based on length of values.

Comment: May I ask how you are planning on spliting by length?